# Is it possible to obtain the Ballistic Weave mod in Fallout 4 without hitting a point of no return?

Tags: fallout-4

So after some reading around today, I discovered that it is possible to upgrade clothing to incorporate ballistic weave.  As somebody who finds power armor to be a bit bulky and unwieldy and not at all flattering to my figure, I love the idea of being able to upgrade clothing for better protection.

According to [this question by k0pernikus](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/243450/is-there-a-point-of-no-return-in-fallout-4), Fallout 4 does have a point of no return, past which certain faction quests will be unavailable.  Additionally, according to an [answer to another question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/244595/20046), this ballistic weave upgrade is only available via a quest from the Railroad faction quest line.  Unfortunately, I really couldn't care less about Synths and don't want to join the Railroad for the end game.

So my question is this: if I go down the Railroad quest route far enough to obtain the ballistic weave mod, will I pass a point of no return?

Comment: Have you not been upgrading your vault suit? Makes for pretty great under-armor protection even late into the game.

Comment: I don't remember being able to upgrade the vault suit, actually.  Instead, I've been wearing a BOS uniform that I looted off a dead body in either the National Guard training yard or the Revere Satellite Array.  I can't remember which.

Comment: You definitely need to get your hands on a vault suit. Not the most "wasteland looking" but it's definitely better than most outfits in the game.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can get ballistic weave without aligning with the Railroad past the point of no return. Based on my experience [and the Fallout Wiki page on Ballistic Weave](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Ballistic_weave), you have to complete two quests (Boston After Dark from Dr. Carrington and Mercer Safehouse from P.A.M.) to unlock the Railroad radiant quest, "Jackpot: {Location}".

The Jackpot quests are given by P.A.M. There are three locations these quests can send you to.

1. Hub 360
2. Medford Memorial Hospital
3. Pinnacle Highrise

After finishing one of these quests, you might be prompted to talk to Tinker Tom about Ballistic Fiber technology found in the cache you recovered. If not, you'll have to continue with the next Jackpot quest.

Most importantly, all of these quests are available before alignment needs to be chosen. The only quest of this chain that actually had any true Railroad story or impact is Boston After Dark (and the prerequisite quest, Tradecraft). Mercer Safehouse is a simple settlement establishment quest, and Jackpot quests are radiant fetch quests.